# Compare generic method signature equality

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to determine if the current class implements any methods with the same signature as a MethodInfo object that I'm getting passed in. (its RealProxy shenanigans)

So I've implemented this method for checking if two (possibly nested, generic) types are equal:

```
Func<Type, Type, bool> checkTypesEqual = null;
checkTypesEqual = (t1, t2) =>
{
    if (t1.IsGenericType && t2.IsGenericType)
    {
        if (t1.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != t2.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
            return false;
        var t1args = t1.GetGenericArguments();
        var t2args = t2.GetGenericArguments();
        if (t1args.Length != t2args.Length)
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < t1args.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!checkTypesEqual(t1args[i], t2args[i]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return t1 == t2;
};
```

With that, I check that the return type is the same, and all of the parameter types are also the same.

Now, consider the following code:

```
var t11 = typeof (Task<Func<string, int>>);
var t22 = typeof (Task<Func<string, int>>);
bool eq = checkTypesEqual(t11, t22);
```

`eq` will be true in this situation, the method is working correctly.

However, if you have a method that has a generic parameter, it would be more like inputting the following:

```
var t11 = typeof (Task<Func<string, int>>);
var t22 = typeof (Task<Func<string, T>>);
bool eq = checkTypesEqual(t11, t22);
```

Now, `eq` will be false because `T != int`, but the method signature still matches (there are no generic constraints). How can I modify my check types method to account for this and return true?

Comment: Since no constraint, T and int is compliance and you shouldn't check types for irrelevant (true/false) check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `type.IsGenericParameter` is the property I was looking for. So I've modified the method as follows, to check if one of the types are a generic parameter and if so just return true.

```
Func<Type, Type, bool> checkTypesEqual = null;
checkTypesEqual = (t1, t2) =>
{
    if (t1.IsGenericParameter || t2.IsGenericParameter) // <-------
        return true;
    if (t1.IsGenericType && t2.IsGenericType)
    {
        if (t1.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != t2.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
            return false;
        var t1args = t1.GetGenericArguments();
        var t2args = t2.GetGenericArguments();
        if (t1args.Length != t2args.Length)
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < t1args.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!checkTypesEqual(t1args[i], t2args[i]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return t1 == t2;
};
```